# Sorting multiple datatype value in Umbraco using ui-sortable in U7

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, umbraco, umbraco7

I want to make a array of data (displayed in a table) sortable in Umbraco 7 using ui-sortable.

Visibly the sort occurs, changing the sort order in the table on the front end after drag and drop, but the index/order doesn't change in the array.

Does anybody know why the array doesn't update?

[Other examples](http://blog.imulus.com/kevin-giszewski/umbraco-7-the-sortable-dynamic-angular-property-editor-example) I have seen show it working but use **model.value** instead of something like **model.value.dataList** (as I am storing multiple values in the datatype).

#### View

```
<tbody class="ui-sortable" ui-sortable="dataSort">
  <tr ng-repeat="value in model.value.dataList">
    <th>{{value.name}}</th>
    <td>{{value.size}}</td>
    <td>{{value.weight}}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

#### JS (dataSort options)

```
...
$scope.dataSort = {
  update: function (e, ui) {
    // shouldn't need to do anything?
  },
  stop: function (e, ui) {
    // shouldn't need to do anything?
  }
};
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an expert on Angular, but it looks like to me you are using jquery `ui-sortable` which, as far as I know, does not care about the underlying data, but focuses only on how the DOM is shown. This means there's nothing hooking up on your array.

I believe you should use `ng-sortable` instead

[Example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dj_straycat/Q5FWt/3/)

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I was trying to see what Umbraco was already doing and though it handled the data, but obviously not. Thanks!